# How to make a td tag perform like checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to make a TD tag in MVC act like a checkbox. If I click on the TD I would like to toggle between checked and not checked. Any Idea on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an old school approach.
Anyway, the way I would do it is by managing the state of the td using client side Javascript, changing for instance the backcolor of the td on click. If you need to post the "form" data you can use a hidden checkbox which is synced in the onClick too. You will need to set each td with an unique ID and call some js function like :

```
function toggleTD(id){
    document.getElementById("checkbox" + id).checked = !document.getElementById("checkbox" +     id).checked;
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox" + id).checked){
        document.getElementById(id).className = something;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(id).className = somethingElse;
    }
}
```